Matrices whose $r$-minors are all nonzero
I am seeking to construct a matrix $M$ of a certain size $n$ such that all its minors of size $r<n$ are nonzero: let's call this property $(\star)$.
I read that this can be done by taking $M = XX^T$ where $X$ is a rectangular matrix of size $(n,r)$, satisfying the same property $(\star)$. Then this can be done by geometric/algebraic considerations, constructing a family of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^r$ such that any subfamily of $r$ vectors is a basis.
However, I do not understand why is $(\star)$ enough. Is it clear that in this case, the matrix $M = XX^T$ would satisfy the same property?

What is property $(\star)$???

If you are just looking for an explicit family of such matrices and you have that $n$ is a prime, you could look at Fourier matrices. This is one of Chebotarev's theorems. If you want help with the specific setup you have, you need to describe what the $(*)$ property is.

@AnCar Sorry, property $(\star)$ is the fact that all the minors of size $r$ are nonzero.

NOTE If you want just a direct solution to the question, feel free to skip ahead to the part after the EDIT tag. I am keeping this original version of the answer simply because it provides a slightly more general idea of finding matrices where all square minors, of any size, are non-zero.
In general, the idea of taking some matrix $X$ of rank $r$ and looking at $XX^T$ is not sufficient. For instance, consider the case $r=1$ and look at the matrix $X=(1,0,\dots,0)^T$. Then $XX^T$ is the matrix with entry $(1,1)$ non-zero but all other entries $0$. So this will have rank $1$, but obviously not all $1\times 1$ minors will be non-zero.
So let us fix $n$ and $r\leq n$.
There is a special case if $n$ is a prime, because then Chebotarev's theorem guarantees that all square minors (of any size) of the Fourier matrix of size $n$ are non-zero. Have a look at Tao's paper from 2005 https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308286 (Lemmas 1.2 and 1.3) for a relatively short and straightforward proof. As an idea, the Fourier matrix of size $n$ is defined as $\mathcal F_n:=\big(w^{k\ell}\big)_{0\leq k,\ell\leq n-1}$, where $w$ is a principal root of unity of order $n$, i.e., $w=e^{2\pi i/n}$.
More generally, we can construct a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that all of its square minors are non-zero (meaning for all sizes $1\leq r\leq n$). To do this, we prove the following lemma.
Lemma Let $p_{1,1},p_{1,2},\dots,p_{1,m},p_{2,1},\dots,p_{m,m}$ be $m^2$ distinct primes and define the matrix \begin{equation}
A:=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{p_{1,1}} & \sqrt{p_{1,2}} & \dots & \sqrt{p_{1,m}} \\ \sqrt{p_{2,1}} & \sqrt{p_{2,2}} & \dots & \sqrt{p_{2,m}} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \sqrt{p_{m,1}} & \sqrt{p_{m,2}} & \dots & \sqrt{p_{m,m}}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Then $\det A\neq 0$.
Proof: We prove this by induction over $m$. The base case $m=1$ is trivial. So now assume that any such matrix of size $(m-1)\times(m-1)$ is invertible and we want to prove that $A$ is invertible. Note that $\det A=\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_m}\epsilon(\sigma)\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^m p_{k,\sigma(k)}}$. Assume $\det A=0$ and let us, for simplicity, set $p:=p_{m,m}$.
We isolate the summands in the Leibniz formula for the determinant that contain $\sqrt{p}$. Then we have that
\begin{equation}
0=\Bigg(\sum_{\tau\in\Sigma_{m-1}}\epsilon(\tau)\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} p_{k,\tau(k)}}\Bigg)\sqrt{p} + \sum_{\mu\in\Sigma_m:\mu(m)\neq m} \epsilon(\mu)\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^m p_{k,\mu(k)}}.
\end{equation}
Note that the coefficient of $\sqrt{p}$ is just the determinant of the $(m-1)\times(m-1)$ matrix obtained by dropping the last row and column of $A$. So by the induction hypothesis, it is not $0$. But this means that $\sqrt{p}$ is an element in the field extension $\mathbb Q\Big[\sqrt{p_{1,1}},\sqrt{p_{1,2}},\dots,\sqrt{p_{m,m-1}}\Big]$, which is a contradiction since all the primes were different. This completes the proof. $\square$
So now we can just take the matrix $P$ of size $n\times n$ with each entry the square root of a different prime. The lemma guarantees that all of its square minors are non-vanishing.
EDIT Thanks to Ted Shifrin for pointing out that I misread what OP said. The matrix $X$ is not just supposed to have rank $r$, but it has to satisfy that all minors of size $r$ are non-zero. We can still use the above Lemma to construct such $X$. Now we prove that if $X$ is an $n\times r$ matrix with property $(*)$, then all $r$-minors of $M=XX^T$ are non-zero.
Property $(*)$ for $X$ can be rephrased as saying that each collection of $r$ rows of $X$ forms a basis of $\mathbb R^d$, where we view each of the selected rows (after transposing it to make it a column vector by convention) as a basis vector. If we denote the respective transpose of the rows of $X$ by $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$, the matrix $M$ is then just the Gram matrix associated to $X$ since $M=\big(\langle X_k, X_\ell\rangle\big)_{1\leq k,\ell\leq n}$.
Pick an arbitrary $r\times r$ minor of $M$. This is equivalent to picking sets $K:=\{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_r\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $L:=\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\dots,\ell_r\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and looking at $M[K,L]:=\big(\langle X_{k_i},X_{\ell_j}\rangle\big)_{1\leq i,j\leq r}$. Let us assume that $\det M[K,L]=0$.
This means that the columns of $M[K,L]$ are linearly dependent, i.e., there are coefficients $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r$, not all zero, such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^r a_j \big(\langle X_{k_i}, X_{\ell_j}\rangle\big)_{1\leq i\leq r}=0
\end{equation}
or equivalently, that for each $1\leq i\leq r$, we have that
\begin{equation}
0=\sum_{j=1}^r a_j \langle X_{k_i}, X_{\ell_j}\rangle=\left\langle X_{k_i}, \sum_{j=1}^r a_j X_{\ell_j}\right\rangle.
\end{equation}
If we set $x=\sum_{j=1}^r a_j X_{\ell_j}\in\mathbb R^d$, we see that $x$ must be orthogonal to each of the vectors $X_{k_1},X_{k_2},\dots,X_{k_r}$. But these vectors form a basis of $\mathbb R^d$, so $x$ must be $0$. But $x$ is just a linear combination of the basis vectors $X_{\ell_1},X_{\ell_2},\dots,X_{\ell_r}$ so this is only possible if $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_r=0$, contradiction. This shows that all the $r\times r$ minors of $M$ are non-zero as desired.

But OP stipulated that $X$ itself had property ($*$).

Oh. I completely missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixing it.
